# Full Screen Mobile Iframe

Tags: html, angularjs, iframe, mobile

I am using Angular and Twitter Bootstrap for a small project but I have run into an issue.  I am attemping to use a template which is shown on a button click to display content in full screen.  Now I have it working with the following iframe display on desktop browsers, but on mobile it does not take up close to the full screen as it is supposed to.

```
<iframe ng-src="{{tab.url | trustAsResourceUrl}}" style="border: 0; position:fixed; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%"></iframe>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: iFrame height is a common problem because of issues determining the height of the parent DOM element and getting the iFrame to expand.  I highly recommend javascript to determine window.height and work with that to set the height as things change for better results.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with a combination of window.innerHeight in angularjs, and also by adding height=device-height to my meta tag.

Thanks for the help!